# conditions on matrices such that operator norms are multiplicative

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given operators $A$ and $B$, with the operator norm, I understand that $||AB||\leq ||A||||B||$ .  I was wondering in what situations does equality hold.

edit: $A$ and $B$ are acting on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and by "operator norm" I mean the supremum norm: i.e $||A|| =\sup_{|x|=1}  |Ax|$

Comment: You will have to be more specific. What are the spaces acted on? What are their norms?

Comment: spaces are $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the euclidean norm.  By operator norm I mean the supremum norm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_norm

Comment: So ... your example to ponder is: $2 \times 2$ diagonal matrix $(1,0)$ times diagonal matrix $(0,1)$.  They both have operator norm $1$, but their product is zero.

Answer (score 2):

In general the equality will hold only in specialized conditions.

The most general condtion I can think of (for the $L^2$ norm)is:

The eigenvector of the largest eigenvalue of $A^T A$ is an eigenvector associated with the largest eigenvalue of $B^T B$

If either $A$ or $B$ is a multiple of an orthonormal matrix then this condition is automatically satisfied.

It is also satisfied if $A$ is symmetric and $B$ is some montonically increasing function of $A$ (at least monotonic in the spectrum of $A$)

Beyond this, you have to handle it on a case by case basis.

Comment: I was thinking along these lines; f'rinstance, if their eigenvectors with the largest eigenvalues are scalar multiples.

Comment: Yes, you are thinking along the right lines. When it comes to norms, you need to look at eigenvalues of $A^t\cdot A$